# Broken Age, how to get the yellow egg from bird by the clowd shoes place

Tags: broken-age

How do i get the bird to move my show shop so i can get the last yellow egg from it? When i try to make it move it just stays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find Jessie's real egg first, and give it back to her.  (Jessie is the bird, IIRC.)

**Solution follows:**

Go left from Jessie's nest

Walk up to the tree (you'll fall through the hole in the clouds) to find Gus and the egg, if you haven't already.

Gus is stuck on a root.  After talking to him, climb back up through the hole in the tree trunk.

Walk over to another "soft spot" visible in the clouds, to the right of the tree.  (There are a couple, if memory serves, so if you guess wrong just come back and use the other one.)

When you fall through this hole you'll land on Gus, knocking him loose.

Now come back to the tree, slide down to the roots, and go get the egg.

Give the egg back to Jessie, and she'll release the golden "fake egg."